# Core DAta: Get a random row from the fetched result

Tags: objective-c, core-data, count

I'm looking for a memory efficient way to take only one row from a fetch result set. This must be random.

I thought using `[context countForFetchRequest:fetch error:nil];` and get an int random value between 0 and that and offset + limit the fetch to 1 result. But I can't find whether or not it doesn't allocate memory for each item it counts.

Is "count" a lightweight operation? Or does it need to instantiate objects in the context before being able to count them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/NSManagedObjectContext.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001182-SW5) is somewhat unclear, but it includes the phrase "number of objects a given fetch request would have returned." Furthermore, Core Data tends to make things like `count` very lightweight - entity instances, for example, allow you to call `count` to find out the number of objects on the end of a to-many relationship without instantiating all those objects or firing that fault. I'd say go for it, but profile it yourself - don't optimize prematurely!